# How to prove Etale morphism at a point.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

How to prove this?
Let G be a finite group acting on a connected normal affine variety.Then the stabilizer at x is trivial iff
Then the orbit space morphism q : X---->X // G is E'tale at x.

Comment: I will assume that you are working over an algebraically closed field. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the completion of $X$ at $x$, and let $\mathcal{O}'$ be the completion of $X/G$ at the image of $x$. Then the fact is that $\mathcal{O}'$ is the ring of invariants in $\mathcal{O}$ under the stabilizer of $x$. In particular, $\mathcal{O}'=\mathcal{O}$ precisely when the stabilizer is trivial.

Comment: I suppose we should also assume the action is faithful for this to be true.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

see SGA1 
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203
Exposé V Corollaire 2.3